# mapReduce and sequential approach

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have some confusion on how data is retrieved in hadoop.

1. Is mapReduce meant to retrieve data from hadoop cluster (HDFS) or it is only confined to aggregation.
2. Hadoop supports sequential search, than how can we say that hadoop process data parallelly, How is search different from processing while traversing through each node?
3. Correct me If I am wrong:
   Is it that The blocks per node are read sequentially but many nodes are processed parallally in the cluster. I mean two jobs run parallelly on two different nodes with each job doing sequential search for all the relevant blocks per node at the same time.
   For example: Node1: Block A. Block B, Block C
               Node2: Block D, Block E, Block F
   my assumption:
                Block A-> Block B-> Block C || Block D, Block E, Block F

where -> is sequential
      || is parallel.

1. Suppose I want to search the one employee out of the four who got maximum benefits (cash) from the company for the last 2 years. How will the search and retrieval work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MapReduce jobs *can* read data from HDFS. Other data sources are possible as well.
2. Please take a look at the [MapReduce tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html) and analyze the map reduce workflow.
3. It strictly depends on the input data size and number of available workers (map / reduce tasks) that will run in parallel on a given node. If you have 3 workers per node, then all three blocks (A, B, C and D, E, F respectively) could be processed in parallel. The data in the block itself is read sequentially from disk.

As far as the example is concerned, your approach could be similar to the following:

- map task: processes all employees and computes local maximum benefits among the employees in a single data chunk and outputs this maximum (i.e. as a pair `[local_max_benefits, employee_id]`
- reduce task: iterates over the local maxima from the map tasks and computes the global maximum as `[local_max_benefits, {employee_id1, ..., employee_idN}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you also tell me that hadoop is more related to database or java programming. I am a pl/sql Developer and i am very much interested in hadoop, i want to explore more of hadoop. Can you tell me how do I proceed.

Comment: Hadoop is all about data processing in a distributed environment. The Hadoop ecosystem is quite broad. Start with the tutorial I linked in 2. in order to get basic understanding about Hadoop. There are projects like Hive (http://hive.apache.org/, data warehouse on hadoop with sql syntax) or Pig (http://pig.apache.org/, sql-like language for data processing on hadoop), which might be more familiar to you as pl/sql developer.